# Key mapping has two definitions in vim?

Tags: vim

When I type `:imap <BS>` in my vim editor, it outputs two lines:

```
i  <BS>        *@<C-R>=AutoPairsDelete()<CR>
i  <BS>        * neocomplete#smart_close_popup()."\<C-H>"
```

The first line starts with '*@' and the second one starts with '*', can one key mapping has over than one definition in vim?

PS: maybe you know, I use spf-vim-13 configurations.

Answer (score 2):

From [`:h map-listing`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#map-listing):

> ```
> Just before the {rhs} a special character can appear:
>   *   indicates that it is not remappable
>   &   indicates that only script-local mappings are remappable
>   @   indicates a buffer-local mapping
> ```

So what you are seeing this that in general `<BS>` is mapped to `neocomplete#smart_close_popup()."\<C-H>"` but in your current buffer only `<BS>` is mapped to `<C-R>=AutoPairsDelete()<CR>`

You probably have a plugin or a ftplugin which remaps `<BS>` for your current buffer depending on its filetype.